# Back-to-back tab order between textBoxes in different groupBoxes

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible to get the following tab order [(according to the numbers in the textBoxes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bewfH.png)?

I have tried setting the same tabIndex for the groupBoxes, but it still jumps through all the textBoxes in groupBox1 before getting to groupBox2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can force a tab order to whatever you want would be to override the `Tab` key.

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Tab:
                  if (txtBox1.Focused)
                  {
                      txtBox2.Focus();
                      return;
                  }
                  else if (txtBox2.Focused)
                  {
                      txtBox3.Focus();
                      return;
                  }
                  else if (txtBox3.Focused)
                  {
                      txtBox4.Focus();
                      return;
                  }
                  else if (txtBox4.Focused)
                  {
                      txtBox1.Focus();
                      return;
                  }
                    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Now, if what your original post meant by changing the Tab order by what the user entered in the boxes, that will be a little trickier.

Comment: This solves my question, but gets ugly with many controls so I went with another layout instead.